# Why are the click coordinates not what I expect?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Why when I click at the beginning or end of a Raphael path element are the coordinates not what I expect?  See example (http://jsfiddle.net/gharabed/prh2J/1/)

In the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gharabed/prh2J/1/), I have a path drawn from (10,10) to (100,100).  If I click at the very tip of the path near 100,100, I get a click event coordinate of something like (107,108).  I can't be more than 4 or 5 pixels away from the end of the line. In fact it looks like I am only 2 (maybe 3 at the most) pixels away.  It seems like the coordinates are a little off.  Am I not considering something here?

```
function sendAlert(e) {
    alert("Clicked at: " + e.x + "," + e.y + "   I would expect it to be near the coordinates in the path defined (10,10) or (100,100)");
}

var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('myid'),200,200);
var line = paper.path('M10,10L100,100');
line.attr({"stroke":"red","stroke-width":4});
line.click(sendAlert);
alert("Click as close as you can to the end of either end of the line segment.")
```

Comment: you'v got coordinates about document, not about svg -element. In example body have margin 8px - it gives difference. Just use position of svg element to correct coordinates

Answer (score 0):

i agree what Vasil has said. i have made a small utility function which will gives you exact coordinates. just pass the mousedown event to this function. ( call this function in your sendalert function)

(i am using javascript).

```
var mainsvg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

    function getSvgCordinates(event) {
                var m = mainsvg.getScreenCTM();
                var p = mainsvg.createSVGPoint();
                var x, y;

                x = event.pageX;
                y = event.pageY;

                p.x = x;
                p.y = y;
                p = p.matrixTransform(m.inverse());

                x = p.x;
                y = p.y;

                x = parseFloat(x.toFixed(3));
                y = parseFloat(y.toFixed(3));

                return {x: x, y: y};
            }
```